# vbscript using date() to get todays date issue

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, vbscript

Hi I am using date() in my script to get todays date automatically. On the form it is showing perfect, however, when this field with the date value is being saved into MS Access database, the value is changing to 6.77751671787457E-05 .... So to conclue in the form it is showing like this: 3/22/2012 (correct) and when saved into the database it is showing like this: 6.77751671787457E-05 (incorrect) .. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What's the type of the column the date is saved to?

Comment: The column type is text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
cADO.Execute "INSERT INTO tblmdfUK (txtDateReg, txtCompany) VALUES (Date(), " & truncForm("txtCompanyName") & ")"
```

Or better, use parameters, though date should not need a parameter in this case, just company name.

Answer (score 2):

Format your date to look like this #yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss# as that's the only format that Access can understand:

```
accessDate="#" &  right("00" & year(date()), 4) & "-" & right("0" & month(date()), 2) & "-" & right("0" & day(date()), 2) & "#"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you save data in text field it may be better to use cstr() before saving.

Comment: Ive tried using cstr but instead of the date, in the database it is showing: 6.77751671787457E-05  .. it should show 03/22/2012 ... I really cannot understand why it is chaging alone

Comment: I am using this:  CStr(date())

Comment: cADO.Execute "INSERT INTO tblmdfUK (txtDateReg, txtCompany) VALUES ("  & CStr(date()) & ", " & truncForm("txtCompanyName") & ")"

Comment: hm, I've just realized your real problem :) You should format you date to look like this #yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss# as that's the only format that Access can understand.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (note the single quotes surrounding the date)

```
cADO.Execute "INSERT INTO tblmdfUK (txtDateReg, txtCompany) VALUES ('" & CStr(date()) & "', " & truncForm("txtCompanyName") & ")"
```

I use this method for now() successfully without CStr.
Place the SQL statement in a variable so you can see it in the immediate window and you'll see the problem:

```
INSERT INTO tblmdfUK (txtDateReg, txtCompany) VALUES (3/22/2012,
```